# Regex hashtag in contenteditable div not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contenteditable, hashtag

How do I change the color of all words that start with the `#` character to blue in a content-editable div while the user is typing. All it does right now is color all the matches but only if they come after a no matched word. Like this:

`#life` randomness `#death` more nothing `#trees`

But this doesn't work:

I ate an apple `#yum` `#doctoraway` `#healthy` `#diet`

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GEm75/

The way I am doing it now is by wrapping each match in a span and then styling it with css. I encountered a problem where the non-matched text after hashtag was still the same color as the hashtag. I solved that, but very inefficiently and I desperately want an alternative.
Here's my code:

```
<div id="box" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 10em" contenteditable="true">
</div>

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
el.focus();
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
    && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.collapse(false);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
} else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

var inp = $('#box');
//select the box div
var text = '';
//#box's default value
inp.on('keyup', function(e) {
    text = inp.html();
    var matches_hash = text.match(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g);
    if (matches_hash) {
        text = text.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g, "</span><span class='hashtag'> #$2</span><span class='else'>");
        inp.html(text);
        placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById('box'));
    }
});
</script>
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Also the problem where hashtags have to be separated by non hashtag text. I ran my regular expressions through a regex tester and it worked fine.

http://regex101.com/r/iF3iZ8

the function placeCaretAtEnd(el) was made by someone else, I did not make it. But all it does is place the caret at the end of the editable div.

If you have questions drop me a comment

Please help me.

Comment: This question is very very very very very general. There is simply no answer to it. What are you doing? What is your architecture? You are asking for a "language" to this in? Have you done *anything* ?

Comment: With all due respect if you're not sure what language you need then a) not sure where we are meant to direct you b) your skill level isn't likely high enough, sorry! You might want to start learning PHP....

Comment: I edited my question and now it is more relevant and easier to answer. Please unclose my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but here's the idea behind one way. Hopefully it'll get your creative juices flowing.

Set up a relational database (possibly [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)) and create a `post` table to store the posts. Let's say the `post` table has these fields:

```
integer unsigned auto increment primary key id
timestamp posted
integer unsigned user_id
text comment
```

Now, you need to make another table to store the hashtags. Let's call this `hashtag` and use this structure:

```
integer unsigned auto increment primary key id
integer unsigned post_id
text tag
```

The `post_id` in the `hashtag` table will point you to the `post` row that the hashtag belongs to. Now, in MySQL, you can run this query:

`SELECT post.* FROM hashtag LEFT JOIN post ON post.id = post_id WHERE tag = "life"`

This query will fetch all the posts with the "life" hashtag.

Comment: thanks. but how would i do the highlighting for the link. On facebook, as soon as you write #life in your status, it puts a blue box around it. How do I do that?

Comment: use Javascript to add `<a>` tags around words that start with "#". Then use CSS to style the link to be the color/font you want.